# Is it possible to redirect a URL from HTTP to HTTPS on the same port for IIS?

Tags: https, http, iis-8.5

I have a website located on a custom port number in the server.
Currently, it is serving the users using HTTP.

I was wondering if it is possible to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS while still reusing the same port number in IIS.
E.g http://www.example.com:8000 becomes https://www.example.com:8000

Some of the information I have seen is that I need to use a second binding.
E.g. Bind port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS and then do a redirect for port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what version of IIS you are using but if it is IIS7/7.5 then IIS URL REwrite will do just fine.

Here is a rule to copy into your root web.config

**URL REWRITE**

*http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite*

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
 <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^1000$" /> 
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}:1443/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: But the question was: *”will IIS actually support running both http and https* **on the same port 8000**”

Comment: The thing is, I am planning to drop the HTTP bindings so only HTTPS bindings are around.

Comment: @amsga If you want the redirect to work, you have to still have the HTTP binding otherwise the server won't respond to a HTTP www.example com request. And no, you cannot have both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port.